# Basic Authentication not working from Android to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: android, sharepoint-2013, basic-authentication

I have been trying since two days to set basic authentication from my android application to SharePoint 2013. I have used HttpUrlConnection,DefaultHttpClient,Retrofit and Volley but these all are showing Authorization failure error. Which is working fine in iOS application.Below is my Vollery code snippet.

```
private void sendJsonrequestSignIn(final String userName, final String password) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.50.31/sites/MobileDev/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/TestData",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("ResponseJson", response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Log.i("ErrorJson", error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String creds = String.format("%s:%s", userName, password);
            String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            params.put("Authorization", auth);
            params.put("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
            return params;
        }

    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Jshare](http://www.independentsoft.de/jshare/). This library supports NTLM and works with Java and Android. I guess this might help with the NTLM authentication in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Authenticator` for basic-auth.

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;


try {
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "password".toCharArray());
        }
    });
    URL url = new URL(DOWNLOAD_URL);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

con.setReadTimeout(10000);
con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.connect();
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but not working, this also return 403 status code. Whether this problem occur from android or Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem before and I fixed it.

Don't use

> Basic Authentication

Use

> NTLM Authentication

I just added a gist for this : https://gist.github.com/franciscerio/4b0a6a969eda3b93098a50174cffd8de#file-gistfile2-txt.

I forgot the original source that helped me. I hope you understand. :)